# Writing statement as algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Write "a number decreased by the sum of the number and eight" as an algebraic expression. Let $x$ represent the number. Then simplify.

- algebraic expression: $x-(8+x)$
- simplified: $-8$

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is correct.

when you say "a number", you have to associate with a variable. here you used $x$.

When you say "The number is decreased by ...", you would display that using the minus sign ($-$).

When you say "The sum of a number and ...", you would display that using the addition between which 2 numbers (or variables) you are adding ($+$).

so you are correct,

It would be:

$$x - (8+x)$$

**NOTE**

This is just for other users on math SE to understand how he arrived at his answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding the details, +1